# Disable scroll inertia in Emacs for macOS (Sierra)

Tags: scrolling

The title pretty much sums it up, I'd like to avoid that the scroll continues when I release the touchpad. Here's my custom variable about the mouse *wheel* behaviour:

```
'(mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(1 ((shift) . 5)))
'(mouse-wheel-progressive-speed nil)
```

To be honest, I'm not sure whether this is is actually inertia or the scroll operations stack up and get executed with some delay hence causing the effect.

The behaviour is observed with `emacs -q` as well.

Comment: why use the touchpad to scroll. Pressing `C-v` or `M-v` should be easier than inconsistent scrolling with touchpad.

Comment: Because sometimes I want to scroll just a few lines.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can disable insertia, but what you can do is, make the cursor position not change while you scroll

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan why using just terminal? Rely on books and use hands to move next/prev 

;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a definitive solution for this:

```
(setq ns-use-mwheel-momentum nil)
```

Also possibly related is the `ns-use-mwheel-acceleration` variable.

---

Tested on macOS Mojave with GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, NS appkit-1348.17 Version 10.10.5 (Build 14F2511)) of 2018-05-31